# change zoom to bounds leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to change the zoom to bounds leaflet map :

this is my code :

```
 map.setMaxBounds(map.getBounds());
    let mapBounds = L.latLngBounds([
        [16.3980555556, -26.63],
        [5.31277777778, -28.1236111111],
    ]);
    map.fitBounds(mapBounds, {padding: [100,100] ,// zoom  });
```

the point is there :

```
map.fitBounds(mapBounds, {padding: [100,100] ,// zoom  ​});
```

how can I add zoom in leaflet map?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: I couldn't find zoom to bounds .there is just padding. but I don't know why padding doesn't work?

Comment: `fitBounds` should zoom the map. No need to mention zoom explicitly. It automatically zooms as needs per provided latlngbounds. https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitbounds

Comment: thanks @Mr_Green so my question is wrong but padding doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like correct syntax except hoping commented `zoom` text didn't also commented the closing brackets. What is the error you are seeing in console or anywhere else?